# Proving $f' = - \frac{\partial{F}/\partial{x}}{\partial{F}/\partial{y}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that, if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are differentiable, $F$ satisfying $F(x,f(x))=0$ and $\partial{F}/\partial{y}\ne 0$ then $$f'(x)=-\frac{\partial{F}/\partial{x}}{\partial{F}/\partial{y}}$$

This appears in a section on the chain rule for many-variables functions, but without knowing the details of $F$ I find it very hard to prove much about it.  To the best of my ability to reason about it, I suppose I could say

$$ \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{x}} + \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}}\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{x}}$$

but for more than one reason I doubt that what I have written is correct.  Yet I'm not exactly sure what's wrong about it, nor can I guess what else I could do.  I tried finding the partial with respect to $y$ but got nothing more useful looking than this.  I also tried writing out limit definitions and saw no useful path forward through that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denoting $g(x) = F(x, f(x))$, we have $g(x) = 0$ so $g'(x) = 0$.

$g'(x) = \partial{F}/\partial{x} + f'(x) \cdot \partial{F}/\partial{y} = 0$ which concludes

Comment: That makes good sense.  But just out of some curiosity or clarification:  Can anything be said about $\partial{F}/\partial{x}$ in terms of the chain rule, directly?  Or does any such claim about it have to be mediated through a function like $g$?

Comment: Im not sure to understand what you mean but if you are intrigued about finding this exercise in the chapter of the chain rule, I would say that you could see it as F(u,v) with u=x and v = f(x), and it simply asks you to compute the partial derivative of F with regard to x